# Using Kendo, how can I delete 1 item from multiple SharePoint lists on click of a button? Already have 1 working, how do I add a 2nd SharePoint list?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, crud

I have the Destroy method working on a Kendo grid. It successfully deletes an item from 1 SharePoint list. However, that same item appears elsewhere in my application because it is also inside another SharePoint list. I'd like to delete that same item from this 2nd list as well, on this 1 click of the Delete button.

Below is the kendo.transport.destroy method that is currently working for 1 SharePoint list. How can I add a 2nd SharePoint list?

```
            destroy: {
                url: function (options) {
                    console.log(options);
                    return _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
                        "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('GalleryItems')/items(" + options.Id + ")"
                },
                cache: false,
                type: 'DELETE',
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),
                    'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose',
                    "If-Match": "*"
                },
                contentType: "application/json"
            }
```

//Destroy command configuration in the columns

```
{
                    command: ["edit",
                        {
                            name: "destroy",
                            text: "Delete",
                            class: "btn-delete"
                        }],
                    title: "&nbsp;"
                }],
```

Comment: Perhaps changing your `destroy` from an Object into a Function? So that in the function, you invoke two ajax calls to delete the item. Or let the back-end handle the delete (i.e. if an item is deleted in list 1, it must also be delete in list 2)? Or maybe the 2nd list just need a refresh?

Comment: thanks, yes I converted the destroy into a function and am now calling 2 ajax calls. The problem is...how do I console.log the 2nd SharePoint list information so that I can delete the ID that correlates with the 1st SharePoint list? It seems like in destroy(options) -- when I console.log(options), only the information from the 1st SharePoint list shows up in the console. Not the 2nd SharePoint list, so I don't know how to target the 2nd SharePoint list's ID?